# SQL error on the database that i don't have it in my project?"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file fail"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\Market\Vina\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I don't have this data base in my project and in my sql server,So why my connection has this error.?

```
<add name="Vina" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MySite;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and my code is:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySite"].ConnectionString);
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be the default connection string for ASP.NET.
You could remove that definition using

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- Remove the inherited conn strings  -->
    <clear />

    <!--   This is your conn string -->
    <add name="Vina" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MySite;
               Integrated Security=True"
               providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

[Some reference on the `<clear/>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ayb15wz8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

MSDN says

> Removes all references to inherited connection strings, allowing only
>   the connection strings that are added by the current add element.